# Magento 1 Core Files

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

Where can I find Magento 1 Core Files ?

I have checked many sources and can't find anything.
As I need to check the modifications applied on Magento core files after implementing our theme.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Ahmed,

Magento 1.9.x module core files are present in app -> code -> core location.

Please find below the relative link to find the module location.

Helpful link: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.9/app/code/core

There can also be a possibility that core file are directly overridden by placing them app > code > local folder with same path structure, In this way also you also need to check local folder as well.

If you are looking for the theme files that are overidden, then you need to go to app -> design -> frontend -> and then you respective theme folder.

Helpful link : https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend